# Insert text inside of a single word. Unique circumstance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very strange out-of-the-box question but there's a good reason for it.

If I have a variable such as:

```
var myText = "Select an option, and we'll update you.";
```

I need to change it to:

```
"Se~lect an option, and we'll up~date you.";
```

Now the symbol is irrelevant. I just need to use a special character of any kind for words that are database related. Select, Update, Count, etc. But I also want to pick a character that isn't used often by the typical person when typing.

I'm hoping there's a way to insert these characters into a list of specified words IF they exist within a variable.

Process:

User enters a comment in a form which the val() is captured in a variable.
Then take the variable and insert a special character inside of those words.

It's on a SQL level that I parse out these characters using replace before they're inserted into the database.

Thank you so much...

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Hopefully you aren't using this for escaping SQL.

Comment: I have a feed that passes this variable through a few courses before it reaches the database. The feed removes words for security purposes. Words like, "Update, Select, Delete" so I need to change the words before reaching the database, and then in the stored procedure I can use replace to remove those characters. It's hard to explain. Position of the character doesn't matter as long as it is within the word, like (S~elect, Selec~t)

Comment: Seems like an XY problem...

Comment: @Blender I'm building a commenting system and the feed resource that I'm using parses out certain words. Not trying to hack a website. :)

Comment: @user1447679: That's a design problem. You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Imagine having a form with an input where you can type, "Hi John... Just wanted to update you on my progress." The word "Update" is stripped out by my feed. So I need to change it before it is sent to the feed, and then I can remove the special character before entered into the database table.

Comment: @user1447679: Are you stripping those words out? Do you have any control over that?

Comment: @JAAulde I haven't tried much, as I can't figure out how to insert a character within certain words of text.

Comment: @Blender Unfortunately no. It's a compiled VB application and I'm using the feed portion "out-of-the-box" to produce the results that I'm needing. Like I said it's hard to explain. I just need to know how to insert a character in specific words. Driving me nuts.

Comment: Honestly a PERFECT example is typing in these comment boxes. That's what I'm building. If I type in update, it shows in here. But my situation is slightly different. It's a facebook/like custom commenting system and the ajax feed process that I'm using has a built in function that strips those words out.

Comment: Or if there's a way to use replace in jquery on words but honor the capitalization. Or would it be easy enough to create an array of words with replacement using index?

Comment: @user1447679: Find a way to fix it. If this is used for security, I don't really want to know what the database side of this looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this should give you a start (if you really must).

Javascript

```
var words = ["select", "update", "count"];

function modify(text) {
    words.forEach(function (word) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "gi"), function(match) {
            var insertAt = Math.floor(match.length / 2);

            return match.slice(0, insertAt) + "~" + match.slice(insertAt);
        });
    });

    return text;
}

console.log(modify("Select an option, and we'll update you. Count. Select an option, and we'll update you."));
```

Output

```
Sel~ect an option, and we'll upd~ate you. Co~unt. Sel~ect an option, and we'll upd~ate you.
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6FNQk/)</kbd>

**Update:** Optimisation

Javascript

```
var words = ["select", "update", "count"],
    regexs = words.map(function (word) {
        return new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "gi");
    });

function modify(text) {
    regexs.forEach(function (regex) {
        text = text.replace(regex, function (match) {
            var insertAt = Math.floor(match.length / 2);

            return match.slice(0, insertAt) + "~" + match.slice(insertAt);
        });
    });

    return text;
}

console.log(modify("Select an option, and we'll update you. Count. Select an option, and we'll update you."));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/BY87v/)</kbd>

Comment: This works great! I'm using parametrized statements with this as well and it's working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Note: You could optimise this some, by creating an array of the `new RegExp`s outside of the function and then loop that array instead of the `words`

Answer (score 0):

If you *absolutely cannot* fix this, you could encode the comment as JSON and represent each character with its unicode escape sequence:

```
function unicode_stringify(s) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        result.push('\\u' + ('0000' + s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)).slice(-4));
    }

    return '"' + result.join('') + '"';
}
```

Decode it on your server and it should work just fine:

```
> unicode_stringify('SELECT * FROM comments')
""\u0053\u0045\u004c\u0045\u0043\u0054\u0020\u002a\u0020\u0046\u0052\u004f\u004d\u0020\u0063\u006f\u006d\u006d\u0065\u006e\u0074\u0073""
> JSON.parse(unicode_stringify('SELECT * FROM comments'))
"SELECT * FROM comments"
```

Please use this only as a last resort.

Comment: I tried this method second and it works as well. Thank you Blender!